# Ethereum Exchanges compatibility matrix? <- concerns due to warnings regarding "smartcontract deposits"

Tags: exchanges, address.transfer

Is there a "exchanges compatibility" features list/matrix, so I know between which I can move Ether directly?

Context+example use case:

I've tried to move Ether between exchanges, however warnings made me concerned, examples:

- Bitstamp warning when I try to withdraw: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzD3C.jpg
- Bitfinex warning when I try to deposit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4MXc.jpg

Therefore, I wondered: Is there some exchanges compatibility matrix/cheatsheet so I don't need to go over support tickets for every exchanges pair?
(Yes, I know I could do transfers through a wallet, but I wondered if I could directly, at least between some pairs of exchanges - to save fees and delay)